# Cannot access Google OAuth via UIWebView in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, uiwebview, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing a phoneGap application and I want to allow signing from different services (Facebook, Twitter, Google). I am using the childBrowser plugin which is actually a UIWebView.

Whenever I try to load specifically Google's OAuth URL `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` with or without the specified parameters, the UIWebView is stuck on loading. If I access that URL from mobile Safari, it works.

From a bit of searching (before posting) I came to the conclusion that it must have something to do with the Certificates from Google. UIWebView doesn't allow unsigned certificates, or something like that.

**RESOLVED**

I had a blank space before https (it was `' https..'` instead of `'https..'`). This caused the webView to get stuck on loading screen.